# Conditional Formatting not applying to cells in range

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Having a issue with conditional formatting in excel, I have a few rules for example:

```
=AND(Q$13>=$M15,Q$13<$O15)
```

Apply to the range:

```
$Q$16:$JU$20
```

Where the row 13 has dates listed by column and M15 and O15 is a date range so if the date in the Q13 is between the date range then fill the cells green. But the formatting only seems to apply to the first row in the range i.e. row 16 and not to row 17:20...

I can't seem to work it out...any advice?

Comment: Check your conditioning formatting rule. You obviously did something wrong.... Or show us your Conditional Formatting Rules Manager Window, so we can see what you did....

Answer (score 0):

If you need the references for M15 and O15 to stay at row 15, then you need to use absolute referencing for the row number.

=AND(Q$13>=$M$15,Q$13

Otherwise the row number will be relative to the currently evaluated row. A screenshot of the data would help.